# Emacs Lisp - How do I handle an edge case where a function returns a string or nil?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm in the process of modifying an Emacs mode. 
https://github.com/bigos/git-auto-commit-mode

I am new to Emacs lisp and I can't find elegant solution to following problem.

I have this code fragment where function gac-raw-branches returns a string or nil and I can't find good solution to avoid errors where split expects a string. I use helper functions like gac-split-for-current shown in the following example. But, is there a better way to do it?

```
(defun gac-split-for-current-branch (raw-branches)
  (split-string raw-branches "\n"))

(defun gac-current-branch (filename)
  "Current git branch of FILENAME."
  (let ((res)
        (raw-branches (gac-raw-branches filename)))
    (if raw-branches
        (dolist (el
                 (gac-split-for-current-branch raw-branches)
                 res)
      (if (string-match "^\\* .*" el)
          (setq res (substring el 2))))
        nil)))
```

Comment: How about something like? `(if (and (not (null ...)) ...) ...)`

Comment: Consider changing the title of this question. It really has nothing to do with handling errors in Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the good-looking (IMO) code:

```
(defun gac-current-branch (filename)
  "Current git branch of FILENAME."
  (let (res)
    (dolist (el (ignore-errors
                  (split-string
                   (gac-raw-branches filename)
                   "\n" t)))
      (when (string-match "^\\* +\\(.*\\)$" el)
        (setq res (match-string 1 el))))
    res))
```

I also kind of like functional style, although it's not recommended for Elisp:

```
(defun gac-current-branch (filename)
  "Current git branch of FILENAME."
  (cl-reduce
   (lambda (res el)
     (or (and (string-match "^\\* +\\(.*\\)$" el)
              (match-string 1 el))
         res))
   (ignore-errors
     (split-string (gac-raw-branches filename) "\n" t))))
```

Some points:

1. I don't like to define functions that are just partial application of one function, like
   `gac-split-for-current-branch`. It makes the code less clear.
2. `(ignore-errors (split-string x))` always returns a list, `nil` at
   worst. It's fine to iterate on `nil` with either `dolist` or
   `mapcar` or `cl-reduce`.
3. No need to write `nil` in else clause of `if` statement: it's automatic.

Answer (score 1):

If a function returns a string or nil, checking that the value is
non-nil (using `if`, `when`, or `and`, depending on the context) is a
fine way to deal with that (at least I don't find it inelegant).

---

Here is one way to rewrite your function (assuming `gac-raw-branches`
is the output of `git branch`).

```
(defun gac-current-branch (filename)
  "Current git branch of FILENAME."
  (let ((gb-output (gac-raw-branches filename)))
    (when gb-output
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert gb-output)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (and (re-search-forward "^\\*\\s-+\\(.*\\)" nil t)
             (match-string 1))))))
```

Note the `when` in the fourth line that is used to make sure there is
a non-nil value.  The `and` in the eigth line serves the same purpose.

---

If you use [dash](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), `-if-let` and
`-when-let` are nice for these situations.

```
(defun gac-current-branch (filename)
  "Current git branch of FILENAME."
  (-when-let (gb-output (gac-raw-branches filename))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert gb-output)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (and (re-search-forward "^\\*\\s-+\\(.*\\)" nil t)
           (match-string 1)))))
```

---

Unrelated to the question, but have you looked into using Magit for
this?  It has a backup mode, but even if that doesn't behave as you
want, you could take advantage of its
[git interface](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/next/magit-git.el).